# Text box is vertical align middle or something... top or text-top won't work

Tags: css, textbox, vertical-alignment

I am using a plugin in WordPress that makes a form, I added a message box (this is a contact form) and gave it my own class, and in the css, I made it taller. That worked just fine, but whenever I click in the box, the cursor things goes to the middle, and it's not wrapping the text. I tried:

```
.messageBoxContactForm {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

and

```
.messageBoxContactForm {
    vertical-align: text-top;
}
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div>
  <label for="messageBox">* Message:</label>
  <input class="messageBoxContactForm ccf-tooltip-field" id="messageBox-1351642237" type="text" name="messageBox" value="">
</div>
```

Remember, this is in WordPress, so there is tons of PHP surrounding it.

Can anyone show me what I need to do?

Comment: Can you provide a simplified example including plain html?

Comment: Yes, show html, please.  Are you trying to center the text within the box or the label next to the box with the box itself?

Comment: Actually, there is no HTML, just php that spits the HTML onto the page. This is what I see in the inspector in Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

input type="text" doesn't wrap, it's not a multi line input and the height of it is completely irrelevant. You want a textarea input.

Try:

```
<input class="messageBoxContactForm ccf-tooltip-field" id="messageBox-1351642237" 
type="textarea" name="messageBox" value="">
```

The possible downside to this is textareas will take new lines.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding the following block,

```
.messageBoxContactForm {
   text-align: left;
}
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-align.asp

Answer (score 0):

Actually your issue is just that you have used the wrong tag `<input>`, you should have used `<textarea>` instead , so your html code should be :

```
<textarea></textarea>
```

and the default text alignment for textarea is top-left.